# Function Call in IF Condition

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to check the function call in "IF condition", but it's not working. I'm getting the output as "**undefined** "My program output supposed to be: 
If user Select a car, then response will be accordingly.
Is my method to get value is wrong?

```js
function carPickUp() {
  var pickedCar = document.getElementById("cars").value;
  return pickedCar;
}

function showCar() {
  var message;
  if (carPickUp() == "ROLLS") {
    message = "Great choice";
  } else if (carPickUp() == "AUDI") {
    message = "best choice";
  } else if (carPickUp() == "VOLVO") {
    message = "Good choice";
  } else if (carPickUp() == "FORD") {
    message = "Good choice";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<h2>The select Element</h2>
<p>The select element defines a drop-down list:</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select id="cars" name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">VOLVO</option>
    <option value="ford">FORD</option>
    <option value="rolls">ROLLS</option>
    <option value="audi">AUDI</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" onclick="showCar()" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: You have lowercase values and uppercase text but you check the value

Comment: Upper-case letters are different from lower-case letters; your `value` attributes all have lower-case values.

Comment: Also DRY: `let message = "Unknown value for car; const value =  carPickUp(); if (value==="rolls") message = "Great choice"; ...`

Comment: Or use a lookup table: `const lookup = ["rolls":"Great choice","audi":"Best choice",.....]; message = lookup[value];`

Comment: if only I had post this 2 hours ago. thank you all.